# Any library for clean code generation from i18n resource bundles?

Tags: java, internationalization

In my project I would like to have compile time checks on my existing resource bundle. I already have a set of `*.properties` localized files and I'm about to hook them up to some `i18n` tool. I was thinking about regular `ResourceBundles`, but I don't like the fact, that this mechanism does not guarantee any kind of checks, neither compile-time or maintenance checks like - finding duplicates or finding unused keys.

So, **I'm looking for a library, which would take my existing `*.properties` files and converted them into neat and clean Java code, which I could use in my project.**

The best possible outcome would be to have a mechanism similar to GWT i18n support. One, clean interface with all messages as a separate methods.

I have looked at [jlibs](http://code.google.com/p/jlibs/wiki/Internationalization) and [ForgeRock](http://commons.forgerock.org/i18n-framework/license.html). I really like jlibs, but it's not a separate lib, so it's hard for me to imagine introducing so huge lib dependency just for i18n. ForgeRock does pretty much what I would like, but it produces constants rather than clean interfaces to work with, like jlibs does.

[This entry blog](http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/01/compiler-aware-internationalization-i18n-with-java-resourcebundle/) is also helpful in understanding which approach I would like to use. I made a big research regarding available i18n tools, I just cannot find 'that one', which would suit my needs the best.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently working exactly on the kind of library you are looking for, [check it out](https://github.com/rodionmoiseev/c10n). It's still work in progress, but I should be having my first release fairly soon.

The first release will just contain support for annotation based translations. I don't yet have any ideas on how to migrate existing projects into c10n style, though. Any ideas, suggestions are always welcome!

Comment: Looks promising, but how stable is it? What's the licence? The tool I choose will be used in commercial product.

Comment: License is Apache License 2.0, so no problem for commercial use. I am afraid I have just started developing it so it's in *alpha* stage right now. Currently there is no stable version available. I was planning to release the first stable version in about a month, but if I have some keen users I can hurry that up a little:)

Comment: I could help a little in a spare time if you keep track of things to do. I might play around a little to give you a feedback from user's perspective and help out with some programming tasks as well.

Comment: @rodion Nice work! The design looks clean and very easy to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the positive feedback. Do feel free to play around. Ideas or even patches are very welcome! I'll jot down something like a roadmap on the wiki.

Comment: @rodion, please provide your email address on Github, since without it I cannot send you a message :)

Answer (score 1):

Another library satisfying your requirements of code generation would be [i18n-binder](http://code.google.com/p/i18n-binder/wiki/GettingStarted#Create_a_Java_source_code_facade_based_on_the_directories_and_pr).

Personally, I would approach this problem from another angle, using the [gettext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext) framework you would mark translatable strings in the source code and generate the resource bundles from them. There are tools and editors that can then update the translations based on the extracted strings, and detect no longer used or modified strings.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I implemented a [Message Compiler](http://www.tmasoft.de/MessageCompiler/index.html), which creates the resource bundle files and constant definitions as Java enum for the keys from one single source file. So the constants can be used in the Java source code, which is a much safer way. The message compiler cannot only be used for Java. It creates also resource files and constants for Objective-C or Swift and can be extended for other Programming environments.

Answer (score -1):

I like JUnit. Not exactly what you are looking for, but by creating tests you are sure that all the items in de propertyfiles are available.